# Can I create blended images with GDAL command line utilities?

Tags: open-source-gis, gdal

I've written a program in Python with GDAL bindings that generates a single band georeferenced GeoTIFF as output.  From there I use the GDAL commandline tool `gdaldem` to colorize that image to highlight certain classes of pixels.  I'd like to also lay it on top of a basemap DEM as final output but I need to do this procedurally in my program as opposed to load both layers into a GIS tool and blend from there.

Are there any GDAL command line utilities I can use to blend two GeoTIFFs together and output a pretty png?

Here's a specific example with some random datasets:

```
  DEM                                  Pixels
```

[image]
[image]

```
  Pixels + DEM Blended (This is what I want to do with command line tools)
```

[image]

**Update:**

I ended up using the `blend` function from PIL like this:

```
basemap_image = Image.open('basemap.png').convert('RGBA')
overlay_image = Image.open('overlay.png').convert('RGBA')
combined = Image.blend(basemap_image, overlay_image, 0.8)
combined.save("out.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use the Python imaging library. PIL.

You will want to load up the first image of the DEM and make sure its in an RGBA format.

```
from PIL import Image

dem_image = Image.open('dem.png').convert('RGBA')
color_pixels = Image.open('pixels.png').convert('RGBA')

combined = dem_image.paste(color_pixels, (0,0), color_pixels)
```

Might need to make sure your color_pixels image has an alpha layer as that's what is used for paste. Otherwise you will have to go through it and create a transparency layer in color_pixels by iterating over the values and setting white to an alpha channel.

Hope that helps, or at least gets you started.

Comment: FYI, the `blend` function turned out to be the most helpful for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not a GDAL expert but this can help you:
http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-raster-merge.html

GDAL have commands to merge, wrap, ... and many more things to do with geo-images.